# compile kernel 2.6.34 for Ubuntu Lucid for xen dom0 / pvops

Tags: ubuntu, xen, kernel, dom0

I'd like to compile a recent Linux kernel (2.6.34) for my Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx AMD64 box, mainly because I'd like to use it as a dom0 kernel with the recent xen4. There's plenty documentation on the web about how to compile a kernel 'Debian style'. But what I think would be nice to start with an 'official' Ubuntu config to be sure not to miss any important things and having to recompile over and over again.

So what I'd like to do is compile 2.6.34, but starting with the 'official' /boot/config-2.6.32-XX from Ubuntu Lucid. The question is: How do I best do that? If I just take the config from 2.6.32, the new features from 2.6.33/34 won't be in the config. So what I'd like to do is somehow the 2.6.34 config with the original 2.6.32 one from Ubuntu. How can I best do that? Does it even make sense? Is there easier ways to achieve what I want?

Thanks for your insight!

A.

PS: I just found a linux-image-2.6.32-bpo.4-xen-amd64 package on backports.org, but no information about it. Would it work as a dom0 kernel on Lucid?

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the Ubuntu 2.6.34 kernel for Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx right now. The kernel is available in their kernel repository.
For complete instructions: [How to compile an Ubuntu Lucid kernel](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/how-to-compile-a-ubuntu-lucid-kernel/).

Comment: It's now possible to compile the 2.6.35 kernel as well. The Ubuntu kernel developers are actively backporting the Maverick (2.6.35) kernel. For complete instructions on how to compile the 2.6.35 kernel:
http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2010/07/14/how-to-compile-a-ubuntu-2-6-35-kernel-for-lucid/

Answer (score 0):

Xen 4.0 can compile only on 2.6.31 or 2.6.32.
Read here http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/Xen4.0?highlight=%28xen%29|%284.0%29

Answer (score 0):

@Peter you misguided every one by giving link to your blog.The OP asked compiling a Dom0 Lucid kernel and not a vanilla kernel which your blog mentions.This is a very cheap way to increase traffic to your blog.Do you even understand what dom0 in terms of Xen means?

@andreash if you want to have a pvops dom0 Kernel on Lucid then follow this link

http://bderzhavets.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/set-up-ubuntu-10-04-server-pv-domu-at-xen-4-0-dom0-pvops-2-6-32-10-kernel-dom0-on-top-of-ubuntu-10-04-server/